# How to implement Virtual scroll on material tree grand child level

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material2, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have an angular mat-tree with parent, child and grand child level. On clicking of child I am adding grandchild in it. But grandchild having huge data upto 4k records. Which is making tree extremely slow. My code as below

```
<div *ngIf="isGrandChildLoaded"><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></div>
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
    <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror" (click)="clickTreeNode(node)">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Please note what I have tried in stackblitz: [My code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkxgao?file=app/tree-flat-overview-example.ts)

I have noted virtual scroll will be the best solution in this case. And I have saw an example: [Refernce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplified-material-tree-with-virtual-scroll?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts)

But in example it is having `virtual-scroll` in whole tree level with full dataSource.

How Can add Virtual scroll in grandchild level with 10 elements at a time. So it wont freeze DOM and Tree. Please guide me...

Answer (score 1):

To virtualize a tree, map the hierarchical data to a flat list such that each item includes original data plus hierarchy info.

This data, for example,

```js
    [{ 
        name: 'item 1', 
        children: [{ 
            name: 'sub item 1', 
            children: [{ 
                name: 'grandchild 1', 
                children: [] 
            }]
        }]
    }]
```

Would become

```js
    [
        { name: 'item 1', depth: 0, parent: null },
        { name: 'sub item 1', depth: 1, parent: /*ref to 'item 1'*/ },
        { name: 'grandchild 1', depth: 2, parent: /*ref to 'sub item 1'*/ }
    ]
```

With the data flattened, it is can be virtualized the same as any flat list. Use the depth to indent elements, and use the `parent` to toggle child item inclusion in the list based on parent expand state.

Also, here's an angular based implementation that I just published. https://github.com/gjcampbell/ooffice/tree/master/projects/of-tree